# How do I callback to a function that is inside the exe?

Tags: c, linux, callback

I have a written code for Windows, and now am trying to port to Linux, but not sure if it is possible or not.

**My Question: I am trying to callback to a function that is in the executable from the shared library. How do I do that?**

This is the compilation output:

```
  Output:
    build/release-linux-ppc64/ioq3ded.ppc64
    build/release-linux-ppc64/ioquake3.ppc64
    build/release-linux-ppc64/baseq3/cgameppc64.so
    build/release-linux-ppc64/baseq3/qagameppc64.so
    build/release-linux-ppc64/baseq3/uippc64.so
    build/release-linux-ppc64/missionpack/cgameppc64.so
    build/release-linux-ppc64/missionpack/qagameppc64.so
    build/release-linux-ppc64/missionpack/uippc64.so

make[2]: Entering directory `/r/home7/XXX/ioquake3'
make[2]: `build/release-linux-ppc64/ioq3ded.ppc64' is up to date.
make[2]: `build/release-linux-ppc64/ioquake3.ppc64' is up to date.
LD build/release-linux-ppc64/baseq3/cgameppc64.so
LD build/release-linux-ppc64/baseq3/qagameppc64.so
LD build/release-linux-ppc64/baseq3/uippc64.so
LD build/release-linux-ppc64/missionpack/cgameppc64.so
LD build/release-linux-ppc64/missionpack/qagameppc64.so
LD build/release-linux-ppc64/missionpack/uippc64.so
```

This is the command that I run to execute my program, that is why I figured "ioq3ded.ppc64" to be my EXECUTABLE.

```
./ioq3ded.ppc64 +set fs_game Mod +set sv_pure 0 +set vm_game 0 +set vm_cgame 0 +set vm_ui 0 +set dedicated 1 +exec something_117.cfg
```

This is the code for Windows:

```
//Called function
__declspec(dllexport) void UnLinkLinkroutingcache( void )
{
      //code
}

//Callback location
#include<windows.h>
typedef void (* fUnLinkLinkroutingcache_t)( void );
void fUnLinkLinkroutingcache( fUnLinkLinkroutingcache_t pUnLinkLinkroutingcache )
{
    pUnLinkLinkroutingcache(); return;
}
fUnLinkLinkroutingcache_t pUnLinkLinkroutingcache;
void callUnlinkLink(void)
{
    HMODULE hLib;
    //fUnLinkLinkroutingcache_t pUnLinkLinkroutingcache;

    hLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("ioquake3.exe"));
    if (hLib == NULL)
        {
        //Module not found, permission denied, ...
        return 0; //inform caller of error
        }

    pUnLinkLinkroutingcache = (fUnLinkLinkroutingcache_t)GetProcAddress(hLib, TEXT("UnLinkLinkroutingcache"));
    if ( pUnLinkLinkroutingcache == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    fUnLinkLinkroutingcache(pUnLinkLinkroutingcache);
}
```

I tried to port this code to Linux, but I can't seem to load the exe.

```
//Called function
extern void UnLinkLinkroutingcache( void )

//Callback location
void callUnlinkLink(void)
{
    void* handle;
    void (*initializer)(void);
    FILE *fp;//zgzg2020

    fp = fopen("HereIsMe.txt", "a");
    if( fp != NULL )
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%d", 1 );
        fprintf(fp, "\n" );
    }
    fclose(fp);

    handle = dlopen("./ioq3ded.ppc64", RTLD_LAZY);
    if(handle == NULL) {
        // report error ...
        fp = fopen("ICantFindFile.txt", "a");
        if( fp != NULL )
        {
            fprintf(fp, "%d", 1 );
            fprintf(fp, "\n" );
        }
        fclose(fp);
        exit(1);return;
    } else {
        initializer = dlsym(handle,"UnLinkLinkroutingcache");
        if(initializer == NULL) {
            // report error ...
            fp = fopen("ICantFindFfunction.txt", "a");
            if( fp != NULL )
            {
                fprintf(fp, "%d", 1 );
                fprintf(fp, "\n" );
            }
            fclose(fp);
            exit(1);return;
        } else {
            // cast initializer to its proper type and use
            (*initializer)();
        }
        // use the result in a call to dlsym
    }
}
```

Comment: `dlerror` will give you more info about the error. Instead of `fprintf(fp, "%d", 1 );` try `fprintf(fp, "%s", dlerror() );` and check the file. As already mention by duskwuff in response, `dlopen` won't work for executables.

Comment: I tried fprintf(fp, "%s", dlerror() ); Now: ]Received signal 11, exiting...                                                                                                                                                     ----- Server Shutdown (Signal caught) -----

Comment: You should really explain what you want to do, without reference to Windows. If we understood your goals, we could help you to achieve them in a Linux way. Don't try to mimic Windows in Linux (or vice versa).

Comment: I thought it might be clearer if I showed the Windows version.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `dlopen` will not suffice for this purpose as many other posters have said. It's only capable of loading shared libraries. If you pass NULL instead of a shared library path, you can look up any symbols that the run-time linker has not stripped from the main executable image (there aren't many).

However, if you want to call functions within an executable compiled without `-rdynamic`, try LD_PRELOAD'ing your own shared library that (on startup) locates the real path to your executable file via `/proc/self/exe`, memory maps it, and then reads the symbol table on that mapping (or other executable headers) to locate and interpret symbols within the main executable.

From there, it's just a matter of defining a few function pointers in your shared library that match the prototype of the function you wish to call, assigning them the location of the symbol in the binary, and calling the function pointer as normal.

Comment: I compiled it again with "-rdunamic", then, handle = dlopen(NULL, RTLD_LAZY);// but, kept on crashing... ><. I can try "LD_PRELOAD", but the "shared Library" is the executable. How do I load it first??

Comment: "It kept on crashing" doesn't explain the problem. I think you're tackling the issue with a few bad assumptions. You should update your question with a better explanation of what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

You can't `dlopen` executables in Linux -- the function only works on shared libraries (`.so`, roughly equivalent to `.dll` on Windows).

What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. I am trying to call a function that is inside the executable from the outside, *.so file. How do  Ido that?

Comment: You cannot do that for a function inside an external executable (because it does not have much sense).

Answer (score 0):

The function dlopen() loads the dynamic library file named by the null-terminated string filename and returns an opaque "handle" for the dynamic library. If filename is NULL, then the returned handle is for the main program. Which does mean it has to be dynamic library.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to say... : (

Answer (score 0):

If ioq3ded.ppc64 is really a .so (doesn't look like it), have you checked what it exports?

Have you checked errno when you get a null return from dlopen (assuming it is a .so file here, as @duskwuff says, everything else would fail)?

Comment: I tried to state it in the title, I am trying to call to a function that is inside the EXE from the outside. Any ideas?

Comment: Put it in a shared library instead of the binary, there really is no other (good) way. For the title I assumed it was a typo.

Comment: I am way too green to try and adventure in the Creation of Linux Libraries... >< Any other suggestions?

Comment: Other suggestion: don't do that; or read material about Linux libraries.

Comment: Basile: You're comments are so unhelpful.